# Наследование объектов в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток!

Хочу сделать свой визуальный компонент, и повесить некоторые триггеры на него. Проблема в том, что не могу повесить триггер на новое свойство, говорит, что его не существует. Как правильно это сделать?

Создал свой класс:

```
public partial class ValidateTextBox : TextBox
{
    public ValidateTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool _IsValide = false;
    public bool IsValide
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsValide;
        }
    }
}
```

Описание XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Class="test_style.ValidateTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <TextBox.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsValide" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </TextBox.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Как правильно обращаться к свойству в созданном компоненте? Получаю ошибку:

Ошибка  1   член "IsValide" не является допустимым, так как не имеет соответствующего имени типа.   F:\Projects\test_style\test_style\UserControl1.xaml 9   32  test_style

Comment: IsValid (без буквы e на конце)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Делайте не так.

Custom control'ы должны быть lookless: они должны задавать лишь поведение, а не внешний вид. (Если вы хотите задать именно вид, вам нужен скорее `UserControl`.) Внешний вид по умолчанию должен даваться через стиль по умолчанию.

Для этого вам нужно следующее:

1. Определите части, с которыми вы хотите общаться в стилях (как вашем стиле по умолчанию, так и в кастомных стилях, которые другие разработчики будут создавать для вашего контрола. Объявите их как `TemplatePart`.
2. Не забудьте перекрыть `DefaultStyleKey`
3. Определите стиль для контрола, и положите его (обязательно!) в `Themes/Generic.xaml` (если только вы не делаете много стилей для разных оформлений Windows)
4. В стиле не забудьте `TargetType`
5. Задайте в стиле `Template`, не забудьте `TargetType` и там
6. Внутри темплейта можно использовать ваши кастомные свойства
7. Чтобы свойство работало правильно, объявите его как DependencyProperty! (Иначе изменения в нём не будут подхватываться контролом.)

Кстати, на английском правильно `IsValid`, без `e`.

Литература: [[1]](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1401/creating-a-wpf-custom-control.aspx), [[2]](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html), [[3]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330302.aspx), [[4]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx).