# Создание пользовательских визуальных элементов

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток. Все же не могу разобраться

В продолжение темы:
[Наследование объектов в WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/259076/c-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-wpf)

Уже упростил работу донельзя. Суть задачи сводится к тому, что нужно пронаследоваться от существующего примитива (например button), добавить дополнительно свойства **bool IsToday** и **bool IsHollyday**. С этим проблем вроде как нет, создал как и на c# класс от button, объявил два свойства на чтение и запись.

Объявил шаблон для кнопки, как учили в умных форумах, в отдельном словаре ресурсов, описал поведение при отсутствии над ней действий, при наведении курсора мыши и при уходе курсора мыши. Но хочется большего.

В качестве content кнопки помещается дата в текстовом виде. *До этого момента дошел*.

Далее мой воспаленный мозг захотел сделать желтенькую рамочку, если флаг IsToday == true, и тело кнопки залить красненьким, если IsHollyday.

Вот куда дальше копать? Как определить поведение для кнопки с учетом введенных новых свойств?

@Vladd кинул ссылки в прошлом вопросе, но что-то не могу разобраться. Может есть что-то на русском по созданию пользовательского визуального элемента не с нуля, а на основе уже существующего?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Покажите то, что уже есть. Вы определили шаблон? Попробуйте добавить транспарентную рамку, и установить жёлтый цвет триггером.

Answer (score 1):

Ну поставьте фоны на кнопку да и всё. Но только это придётся переопределять onDraw(). В xml делаете фон прозрачным (#00000000), а в он дрове вручную рисуете фон с помощью canvas.drawColor и canvas.drawBitmap, а потом вызывается super.onDraw. Но это лишь один из способов, так делал я по крайней мере =)

Comment: Какое `onDraw`? Это WPF. Стили и триггеры, только стили и триггеры.