# Переопределение Style у UserControl`а

Tags: c#, wpf

Когда я переопределяю стиль у ModernBtn в Window1 по сути я убираю у него свойство Template. Из-за этого вылетают ошибки. Подскажите как сделать так чтоб при присваивании стиля в Window1 свойство Template всегда было таким как в ModerBtn.xaml

ModernBtn.xaml.cs

```
Color bgColor;
    Rectangle indicator;
    Border mainBorder;
    public ModernBTN()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += delegate (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            indicator = (Rectangle)this.myBtn.GetTemplateChild("indicatorBtn");
            mainBorder = (Border)this.myBtn.GetTemplateChild("mainBorder");
            bgColor = ((SolidColorBrush)mainBorder.Background).Color;
            MouseEnter += EnterAnim;
            MouseLeave += LeaveAnim;

        };
    }
```

Mindow1.xaml

```
<ModernButton:ModernBTN BtnText="Menu: " Foreground="White" CornerRadius="20">
            <ModernButton:ModernBTN.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ModernButton:ModernBTN">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ButtonColor" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BGHover" Value="#A4A4A4"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ForeColor" Value="#646363"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LightStyle}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BGHover" Value="White"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="ForeColor" Value="#A4A4A4"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ModernButton:ModernBTN.Style>
        </ModernButton:ModernBTN>
```

ModernBtn.xaml

```
<Button x:Class="ModernButton.ModernBTN"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModernButton"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200" Name="myBtn" Background="Transparent">
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=ButtonColor}" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=CornerRadius}" Name="mainBorder">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=BtnText}" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=ForeColor}"></TextBlock>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Lime" Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20" Name="indicatorBtn" Width="0"></Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Comment: @ПавелЕриков проблема из этого вопроса (не второго, который закрыли, все ещё актуальна)?

Comment: Из этого вопроса "Переопределение Style у UserControl`а" все еще актуальна и я так понял будет актуальная еще неделю. тк почему то никто не знает как решить это

Comment: Я снесу комменты, которые относились к первой редакции вопроса

Comment: А какие конкретно ошибки? Дайте текст исключения и строку, на которой оно возникает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ — это унаследовать стили. Например, так:

В App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ModernBtnStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=ButtonColor}" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=CornerRadius}" Name="mainBorder">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=BtnText}" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=ForeColor}"></TextBlock>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Lime" Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20" Name="indicatorBtn" Width="0"></Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

В ModernBtn.xaml:

```
<Button x:Class="ModernButton.ModernBTN"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModernButton"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200" Name="myBtn" Background="Transparent"
         Style="{StaticResource ModernBtnStyle}">
</Button>
```

Ну и в MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="ModernButton:ModernBTN" BasedOn="{StaticResource ModernBtnStyle}">
```

---

Более правильный путь — вы должны выучить, как делаются custom control'ы. Вам придётся унаследоваться без XAML-файла, а просто обыкновенным наследованием классов. Переопределять шаблон по умолчанию нужно в Generic.xaml. Код с объяснениями можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586733/10105). Затем, чтобы получить доступ к шаблону, вам понадобится перекрыть `OnApplyTemplate`, и запрашивать `GetTemplateChild` именно там. Пример этого [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443963/10105). Checklist для custom control'а [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/259086/10105).

При этом ваш шаблон из ModernBtn.xaml окажется в Generic.xaml, а стиль из MainWindow.xaml станет обыкновенным стилем, и не будет «ломать» шаблон.

Дерзайте!