# Почему свойство = null?

Tags: c#, wpf, style, usercontrol

Я сделал свой UserConrol типа Button
ModernBtn.xaml

```
<Button x:Class="ModernButton.ModernBTN"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModernButton"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200" Name="myBtn" Background="Transparent">
<Button.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="default"></Style>
</Button.Resources>
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource default}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=ButtonColor}" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=CornerRadius}" Name="mainBorder">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=BtnText}" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=ForeColor}"></TextBlock>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Lime" Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20" Name="indicatorBtn" Width="0"></Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

и часть ModerBtn.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ModernBTN : Button
{
    public Style ModernStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(ModernStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModernStyleProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("ModernStyle"); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModernStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ModernStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(ModernBTN));

    Color bgColor;
    Rectangle indicator;
    Border mainBorder;
    public ModernBTN()
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Resources["default"] = ModernStyle;
        this.Loaded += delegate (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            indicator = (Rectangle)this.myBtn.GetTemplateChild("indicatorBtn");
            mainBorder = (Border)this.myBtn.GetTemplateChild("mainBorder");
            bgColor = ((SolidColorBrush)mainBorder.Background).Color;
            MouseEnter += EnterAnim;
            MouseLeave += LeaveAnim;                            
        };
    }
```

почему ModernStyle = null; в строчке

> this.Resources["default"] = ModernStyle;

хотя поидее я же указываю ModernStyle

```
<ModernButton:ModernBTN ButtonColor="Silver" CornerRadius="20" BGHover="Black" ForeColor="White">
        <ModernButton:ModernBTN.ModernStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ModernButton:ModernBTN}">
                <Setter Property="BtnText" Value="Menu: "></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="300"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ModernButton:ModernBTN.ModernStyle>
    </ModernButton:ModernBTN>
```

Вообще идея в том чтоб я указывал стиль у кнопки и базовый стиль с ControlTemplate наследовался от стиля который я установил.

1) Как исправить ошибку чтоб все работало?
2) Если идеи как сделать проще?

Сорри за нытье но если можете чем то помочь то подскажите. Сижу уже 2 дня голову ломаю.

В вопросе который якобы дубликат была ошибка в том что стиль с ControlTemplate убирался скажем так. И кнопки считай и не было. Здесь ошибка в другом но я не знаю в чем.

Comment: Перестаньте проблемную строчку пониже, после InitializeComponents.

Comment: @PashaPash: может, добавить в графу «Дубликат» ссылки на частые вопросы? К примеру, я в последнее время ну слишком часто вижу вопросы про `NullReferenceException`. И все они сводятся к тому, что ТС не умеет пользоваться отладчиком и/или просто не понимает смысла данного исключения. Бедный **Athari** и **VladD** в [этом всем известном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/248572) разложили все по полочкам. Так что всегда приходится флагать подобные вопросы и искать ссылку на тот первоисточник. Можно было бы сократить работу сообществу)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov вы не поверите, но [это вопрос уже закрыли как дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/889873/revisions) что такое "NullReferenceException", и я его переоткрыл по просьбе VladD. Проблема с "замечательным" вопросом про NullReferenceException в том, что на него закрывают даже те вопросы, где топикастер **понимает** что проблема в значении null, но по незнанию местной специфики упоминает NullReferenceException в теле вопроса - и вопрос сразу закрывают с указанием в качестве основного полностью неприменимого "канонического".

Comment: @Kir_Antipov вот, смотрите, топикастер тут спрашивает "почему ModernStyle = null; в строчке такой-то" (или "myBtn было null", как было в первой редакции). Он понимает, что проблема в null, и пытается понять, почему именно null. А вы ему - "у тебя NullReferenceException, потому что у тебя значение null". Как-то неправильно :)

Comment: @PashaPash: согласен, я в нулевой редакции не разглядел, что ТС понимал, что у него `myBtn == null`. Так что да, тут все нормально) Хотя заголовок лучше подправить, а то сонные люди вроде меня как раз и пойдут, не сильно вчитываясь, флаговать)

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, `myBtn` — поле вашего класса `ModernBTN`. (Оно не видно вам, т. к. генерируется в partial-части класса, генерируемой из XAML-разметки.)

Инициализация этого поля происходит в конструкторе, внутри вызова `InitializeComponent()`. Поэтому *до* этого вызова `myBtn` всё ещё `null`.

Перенесите обращение к `myBtn` ниже, на строчку после `InitializeComponent()`.

Ещё проще: внутри класса `ModernBTN` значение `myBtn` — это просто ваша кнопка, так что вы можете просто использовать вместо него `this`, его-то значение точно не будет равно `null`.

Comment: Да емае :) я уже давно понял это! Вы вопрос пересмотрите! Почему ModernStyle = null?

Answer (score 1):

Окей, вопрос изменился, вот ответ к изменённому вопросу.

Смотрите, что означает

```
<ModernButton:ModernBTN ButtonColor="Silver" CornerRadius="20" BGHover="Black" ForeColor="White">
    <ModernButton:ModernBTN.ModernStyle>
        ...
```

Этот код находится вне класса `ModernBTN`, и выполняется следующим образом: вызывается конструктор `ModernBTN`, и после того, как он отработает, устанавливаются свойства наподобие `ButtonColor` или `ModernStyle`. (Сам код выполняется, очевидно, в контексте `InitializeComponent()` вашего окна.) Поэтому, понятно, во время пробега конструктора значение свойства равно `null`, ведь его ещё никто не установил.

---

Ваш подход неверен. Вы пытаетесь унаследоваться от динамически устанавливаемого стиля через code behind, и пытаетесь подгадать момент, в который свойства объектов будут установлены. Хотя этот подход можно «продавить», я бы крайне не рекомендовал этот путь, проблемы будут встречаться на каждом шагу.

Сделайте стиль `default` статическим, и положите его в `App.xaml`, а не пытайтесь установить его динамически. Будет намного проще.

Comment: Как я могу стиль default сделать статическим я так понял в xaml? И потом как конкретней мне изменить код? Не очень понял.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков: Ну, положите его в App.xaml, в секцию ресурсов. Как вот тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889995/10105

Comment: И типо все будет работать как нужно? Блин не очень то что я хотел! Тоесть вы предлагаете просто в основном проекте определить стиль кнопки с Tempalte моей кнопки. АААА трудно

Comment: @ПавелЕриков: А, это у вас не основной проект, а DLL? Тогда делайте как пишется во второй половине [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889995/10105), создавайте настоящий custom control.

Comment: Скиньте пожалуйста ссылки на книги или видео курсы про custom control попробую разобраться.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков: Видеокурсов не знаю, а ссылки на документацию и другие ответы с подробными примерами есть в моём другом ответе.

Comment: Или если есть какой нибудь конкретный пример с моей проблемой. А то не могу в гугле найти!

Comment: У меня появилась идея а можно как то сделать так. Создать стиль в code behind где Property = Template. (не знаю почему в code behind) и потом при установке ModernStyle

Comment: при присваивании ModerStyle добовлять к (Style)value.BaseOn = тот стиль который сделали и ток тогда SetValue. Будет ли работать?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков: Вы пытаетесь найти какой-то обходной путь, чтобы не делать правильно. На обходном пути вас подстерегают проблемы на каждом шагу. Я бы порекомендовал сделать нормальный custom control (примеры я вам дал же), а потом, если хочется поэкспериментировть, пробовать нестандартный путь.